# PHP. Не понимаю почему не работает

Tags: php, html

Написал код для решения задачи ->

> Написать функцию, принимающую число n – количество квадратов. Функция
> имеет вывести на черном фоне n красных квадратов случайного размера в
> случайной позиции в браузере

Вот сам код ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black;">
    <?php
            
            for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
                $a = rand(10, 100);
                echo "<div style='width: $a px; height: $a px; margin: $a; padding: $a; background-color: red'></div>";
            }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Створити">  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вместо ввода значения пользователем "n" я поставил временно количество 10, но суть в другом.
Код просто не работает, выводит чёрный фон и кнопку, хотя должен выводить разные по размеру и расположению кубики красного цвета, можете пожалуйста подсказать в чём проблема и так же не буду против советов по улучшению кода, сильно не бить, я новичок в php )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если смотреть на логику **CSS**, а не *PHP*, то значение в виде

```
20 px
```

навалидно, а вот  так:

```
20px
```

вполне себе. Понимаете намёк?

А уж значение `margin: 15` (15 - значение для примера) без указания единицы и подавно

Comment: "margin: 15" без указания пикселей или вообще чего либо потому что это была попытка без них запустить программу, так сказать отринул логику в попытка починить программу. А насчёт "20 px" and "20px", а как тогда делать с учётом переменной ? - "width: $a px"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex   фигурные скобки использовать

Comment: Понял, всё заработало, большое спасибо